# angularjs + requirejs = Argument 'controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading

Hi i am trying to implement angularjs + requirejs but i get Argument 'HelloWorld' is not a function, got undefined error when i go to desired path

app.js

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "",
paths: {
    'domReady': 'Scripts/RequireJs/dom-ready/domReady',
    "angular": "Scripts/AngularJs/angular",
    "angular-route": "Scripts/AngularJs/angular-route",
    "angular-resource": "Scripts/AngularJs/angular-resource",
},
shim: {
    "angular": {
        exports: "angular"
    },
    "angular-resource": {
        deps: ["angular"]
    },
    "angular-route": {
        deps: ["angular"]
    }
}
});

define('app', ['angular', 'angular-route'], function (angular) {
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {

    app.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
    app.compileProvider = $compileProvider;
    app.routeProvider = $routeProvider;
    app.filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    app.provide = $provide;

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        resolve: {
            load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                require(['App/home'], function () {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });

                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }
    });
});

require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});

return app;
});
```

home.js

```
require(['app'], function (app) {
app.controllerProvider.register('HelloWorld', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greet = function () {
        return 'Hello World!'
    }
});
});
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="HelloWorld">
    {{greet();}}
</div>
```

as i understand whats happening when i go to /home angular looks for a controller named HelloWorld cant find it throws Argument 'HelloWorld' is not a function, got undefined then my debugger gets hit in home.js but all i see on screen is {{greet();}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

**1.** `require.config` should ideally be placed inside a `main.js` and loaded in your `index.html` using:

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src=".../require.js"></script>
```

**2.** Try to define controller in your route and remove `ng-controller` home.html:

```
...
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'HelloWorld', // <-- Need to add this line
...
```

**3.** Your home.js should be using `define` instead of `require` as you are defining a module here.

I created the following project to facilitate the use of RequireJS and AngularJS that you should take a look:
https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD

Comment: it was indeed wrapping my home.js with define instead of require. When i wrap it with define, before angular could check the attr 'HomeWorld' my debugger in home.js got hit then everything worked as expected but how and why? or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Where is "angular could check the attr 'HomeWorld'"?

Comment: all i know that when i used require it gave me HelloWorld not function error only after that my debugger got hit in home.js but when i used define on home.js no error everything works perfect why

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, if you use `require` in your home.js it breaks.  The reason is that require loads a module and RequireJS expect the target file is a module defined using the `define` method.  Remember that you are calling `home/app` using `require` statement in your `$routeProvider`

Comment: so i used define because i am loading it from somewhere else i completly ignored the fact that i am loading it from somewhere else (using require) i thought it as it's just a piece of code that requires "app" now i understrand require.js better thank you

Comment: This breaks if you do a form submit and redirect to another page and then come back to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Looks good to me. Perhaps your 'App/home' should be 'app/home'  not sure how you did define your 'App'. In case it still does not work. Try adding 'app' in your config.

I made this working version of your thing: 
https://github.com/guilbep/smallrequirejsangularseed